# CiviEvent - Activity Attendance Tracking With Multiple Check-ins/outs

Tags: civievent

*Thank you to all responses in advance.

I am trying to determine whether or not there is a viable solution to the following scenario:

I am working for a non-profit center that has implemented various daily programs (could also think of them as "Stations") (will also be recurring daily) for the children to participate in. Examples: Athletics, Study Hall, Arts & Crafts, etc.

In the scenario I am envisioning, each child would be able to go up to a computer kiosk/ipad, (Ideally via a front-end CiviEvent form/registration) enter in their Name and/or ID number (just a 4 digit number associated to each child) and "clock-in" to the program of their choice. Should they want to rotate to a different program, they would "clock-out" (or at least a way to monitor how much time they spent in X program) before "clocking-in" to another program/station. Typically, each child goes to 3 stations per day.

As for reporting, really only have a question on 1 item, the rest should be possible:

- How many minutes a day on average did total number of children participate in X program.